# Join two JSON files and create a new one

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I can't find a lookup table where all country codes are packed together with their names in different languages, so I have to create my own file.

Let's start with two languages, German and English.

German JSON file example:

```
[{"id":4,"name":"Afghanistan","alpha2":"af","alpha3":"afg"},
{"id":818,"name":"Ägypten","alpha2":"eg","alpha3":"egy"},
{"id":248,"name":"Åland","alpha2":"ax","alpha3":"ala"},
{"id":8,"name":"Albanien","alpha2":"al","alpha3":"alb"},
{"id":12,"name":"Algerien","alpha2":"dz","alpha3":"dza"}]
```

English JSON file example:

```
[{"id":4,"name":"Afghanistan","alpha2":"af","alpha3":"afg"},
{"id":248,"name":"Åland Islands","alpha2":"ax","alpha3":"ala"},
{"id":8,"name":"Albania","alpha2":"al","alpha3":"alb"},
{"id":12,"name":"Algeria","alpha2":"dz","alpha3":"dza"},
{"id":16,"name":"American Samoa","alpha2":"as","alpha3":"asm"},
```

I can read both files like that

```
with open('german.json') as fd:
    ger = json.load(fd)
```

Since we have unique ids for the countries we can join them together.
The result should look something like that

```
[{"id":4,"ger":"Afghanistan","eng":"Afghanistan","alpha2":"af","alpha3":"afg"},
{"id":818,"ger":"Ägypten","eng":"Egypt","alpha2":"eg","alpha3":"egy"},
{"id":248,"ger":"Åland","eng":"Åland Islands","alpha2":"ax","alpha3":"ala"},
{"id":8,"ger":"Albanien","eng":"Albania","alpha2":"al","alpha3":"alb"},
{"id":12,"ger":"Algerien","eng":"Algeria","alpha2":"dz","alpha3":"dza"}]
```

What's the most effective way to join the lists together considering that other languages can be added in the future?

Comment: What did you try? Looks like you want others to do the work for you.  If you want a hint; try using a `pandas.DataFrame` to merge, and then write back to JSON again.

Comment: If you want an extensible solution you will have to define the rules for determining keys such as 'ger' and 'eng'. Also, the examples you've given appear to be lists/arrays and not valid JSON

Comment: @suvayu +1 for the hint with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments it's easier to load the files into dataframes and merge them together.
A working solution would be

```
german = pd.read_json('world.json')
english = pd.read_json('world_en.json')

lookup = pd.merge(german, english, on='id')
lookup = lookup.drop(columns=['alpha2_y', 'alpha3_y'])
lookup = lookup.rename(columns={'name_x': 'de', 'name_y': 'en', 'alpha2_x': 'alpha2', 'alpha3_x': 'alpha3'})
lookup = lookup[['id', 'de', 'en', 'alpha2', 'alpha3']]

lookup.to_json('lookup.json', orient='records')
```

Only downside with this solution is we have to drop and rename more and more columns with more languages.

Comment: The `alpha*` columns aren't changing, so you could rename the first one and use `.assign`, like this: `df.rename({"name": "de"}).assign(lang1=other1.name, lang2=other2.name, ...)`.  Adding new languages would mean adding one more argument, that's it.